# Let scanf, gets etc. read from a pipe (WinAPI)

Tags: winapi, pipe, scanf

I want to send a program which probably uses scanf, gets or something like that, some input by using a pipe from a winapi-program. Writing seems to work, but what do i have to do to make the other program read this input?

an example would be like this:

```
int main()
{
 HANDLE outputhandlewrite;
 HANDLE outputhandleread;
 HANDLE inputhandlewrite;
 HANDLE inputhandleread;

 char gdbpath = ".\SysGCC\bin\arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb.exe";
 char gdbcommand = "help";

 SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

 PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
 STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;

 BOOL bSuccess

 saAttr.nLength = sizeof(saAttr);
 saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
 saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

 CreatePipe(&outputhandleread,&outputhandlewrite,&saAttr,0);
 SetHandleInformation(outputhandleread,HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,0);
 CreatePipe(&inputhandleread,&inputhandlewrite,&saAttr,0);
 SetHandleInformation(inputhandlewrite,HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,0);

 ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo,sizeof(piProcInfo));
 ZeroMemory(siStartInfo,sizeof(siStartInfo));

 siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
 siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
 siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
 siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
 siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

CreateProcess(NULL,gdbpath,NULL,NULL,TRUE,0,NULL,NULL,&piProcInfo,&siStartInfo);

for (;;)
{
for (i = 0; i < (*ds).mds.mdscs.debuggerlineswidth; i++)
{
    bSuccess = ReadFile((*ds).debuggeroutputdata.outputhandle, pipebuffer + i, 1, &bytesread, NULL);

    if (*(pipebuffer + i) == '\r')
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile((*ds).debuggeroutputdata.outputhandle, pipebuffer + i, 1, &bytesread, NULL);
        break;
    }
}

*(pipebuffer + i) = 0;

//Here is just Code for printing the received ouput to the window
}

        bSuccess = WriteFile((*ds).debuggerinputdata.inputhandle, (*ds).debuggerinputdata.inputstring, strlen((*ds).debuggerinputdata.inputstring) + 1, &byteswritten, NULL);
        bSuccess = WriteFile((*ds).debuggerinputdata.inputhandle, (*ds).debuggerinputdata.inputstring, 0, &byteswritten, NULL);
}
```

Creating the process works, reading works and WriteFile returns success and bytes written is equal to the length of the input string.`enter code here`

Comment: Please edit your post to add [mcve] that shows what you have come up with so far.

Comment: Hard to tell without a [mcve], but the most likely cause (given the additional information in your "answer") is that you forgot to send an end-of-line, or didn't send the *right* end of line.  I'm not entirely sure, but I think in this scenario you'd need to send a Windows end of line sequence, i.e., a carriage return followed by a line feed.

Comment: ["Be careful when redirecting both a process’s stdin and stdout to pipes, for you can easily deadlock"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110707-00/?p=10223). Also ["Redirecting output can result in altered program behavior"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060519-09/?p=31133/).

Comment: This [support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/190351/how-to-spawn-console-processes-with-redirected-standard-handles) has additional info aswell as a better example which uses a thread to provide input to the child process, which is also suggested by Raymond Chen in the first link above.

Comment: and for what you use 2 pipes pair, when enough use single pipe pair. for avoid  deadlock the best use asynchronous io for pipe

Comment: The posted code is clearly incomplete, you use a number of variables that are neither declared nor initialized.  I take it from your deleted answer that you have also tried this using a child process you wrote yourself, that would be a very good starting point for a [mcve], you just need to remove any extraneous content, make sure the code still compiles and demonstrates the problem you're having, and then post the complete code for both the parent and child.  Otherwise, we're just guessing at random.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) pass in a [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) instance in passing the end of the pipe you read from as the standard input handle.

If I recall correctly you'll need to have created the pipe with inheritable handles.

Comment: You certainly don't need Named Pipe to redirect a child process. Anonymous pipes are sufficient.

Comment: @zett42 oops: I always seem to forget Win32 has those as well :-).

Comment: @zett42 - Anonymous pipes this is the same as Named Pipe. the same object, only without (begin from win7 ) or random name